# Selenium WebDriver 2.40 - Unable to take screenshot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The below statement worked really fine with Selenium webdriver 2.39. After upgrading this to webdriver 2.40, below statement does not work.

```
            File scrFile=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/output//files/"+fileName));
```

It throws this exception.
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot

anyone has anyidea on how to fix this?

EDIT: I did not modify the above code. Only change i did is to replace the selenium-java-2.39.0.jar with the selenium-java-2.40.0.jar.

Comment: How you are launching your browser? How you initiating Web Driver instance?

Comment: driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("<some site>");


As i had mentioned above, it takes screenshot if i have selenium-java-2.39.0.jar. if i try to replace with selenium-java-2.40.0.jar , then i get the exception only when i take the screenshot. No change in the code.

Looks weird. 

Can someone plz confirm if you are using the same jar i use - selenium-java-2.40.0.jar ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved.

I had selendroid jar as well associated to the test(which is used to run my tests in Android devices).  Due to the order of the jars in the classpath, selendroid jar was causing the issue. When i changed the order (selenium jar first , selendroid next), error is gone.

Thank You All.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking that you're using the Java 7 compiler.
Here's my snippet working fine with Chrome:

```
TakesScreenshot yourScreenshot = ( TakesScreenshot ) driver;

File tempfile = yourScreenshot.getScreenshotAs( OutputType.FILE );
System.out.println( tempfile.getAbsolutePath() );

File myScreenshotDirectory = new File( "Screenshots Folder" );
myScreenshotDirectory.mkdirs();

File screenshotImage = new File( myScreenshotDirectory,"ScreenShotImage.png" );
FileUtils.moveFile( tempfile, screenshotImage );
```

Comment: Yes. I have jdk1.7 installed.
TakesScreenshot yourScreenshot = ( TakesScreenshot ) driver --> this is where exception occurs.

Comment: I think this should be fine just verified on my machine with both chrome and Firefox Drivers.

I can see that you casted your driver

Comment: I have included this jar. selenium-java-2.40.0.jar
If it is working fine for you, can you please let me know what are all the jars (related to this) you have associated?

Comment: I get all the Jars Via Maven Dependencies (Selenium Java 2.40.0 and FirefoxDriver)